# Is Hadoop MapReduce MapContext.write() thread safe?

Tags: java, hadoop

Traditionally a Hadoop MapReduce mapper sequentially processes data and emits values by writing to the map context, as this example excerpt from the [`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) API docs shows:

```java
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
}
```

But what if the mapper decides to start up several threads, each of them doing a portion of the work (sort of a further divide-and-conquer within the mapper)? Each one will want to emit data when it is ready.

Does `MapContext.write()` (really [`TaskInputOutputContext.write(KEYOUT key, VALUEOUT value)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskInputOutputContext.html#write-KEYOUT-VALUEOUT-)) support being called concurrently within the mapper? Or must I synchronize the calls to `MapContext.write()` and guarantee they are called sequentially? (And what sort of bad things would happen if I should and I don't?)

(I anticipate replies saying I shouldn't be starting up multiple threads in a mapper in the first place. While I respect that point of view, pragmatically this is what I'm working with at the moment.)

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't by default. That's why they let you override the `run()` method, which handles the flow of the mapper operations.

This is the [source code](https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java), and default implementation for **`run`**:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    cleanup(context);
}
```

And at the very end of the [Mapper javaDoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#run-org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context-), this phrase gives some light:

> **Applications may override** the
> `run(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context)` method to exert
> greater control on map processing e.g. **multi-threaded Mappers** etc.

So the idea is clear; You want thread-safety on multithread environment, that's cool...but you implement the logic. A **very basic** example of this could be (*I synch all, because I don't know the details of each method/element, just for the example*):

```
@Override
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    synchronized(lock)   //shared lock, class lock, etc..
   { 
      setup(context);
      while (context.nextKeyValue()) 
        map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
      
      cleanup(context);
    }
}
```

---

Although there's no specific mention to multithreading with this method, something similar happens with `map()`:

> `protected void map`
>
> Called once for each key/value pair in the input
> split. **Most applications should override this**, but the default is the
> identity function.

---

In resume, overriding these methods (at least one of them), should let you create a multithread `Mapper` extension.

So yes, **it can be thread-safe,** but it's your job to do so. The **default implementation is not**.

---

### Update - *MultithreadedMapper*

Well, they do offer a multithreaded runnable mapper implementation:
Anyway, seems like the synchronization regarding the map/write operations are still your job; This just implements the mechanism to invoke run() from different pooled threads.

**[MultithreadedMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html)**

> Multithreaded implementation for @link
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper. It can be used instead of the
> default implementation, MapRunner, when the Map operation is not CPU
> bound in order to improve throughput.
>
> **Mapper implementations using this MapRunnable must be thread-safe.**
>
> The Map-Reduce job has to be configured with the mapper to use via
> setMapperClass(Job, Class) and the number of thread the thread-pool
> can use with the getNumberOfThreads(JobContext) method. The default
> value is 10 threads.

The key here seems to be the [setMapperClass()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html#setMapperClass-org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job-java.lang.Class-) method; There a custom thread-safe extension of `Mapper` should be passed as argument.

### --
Appendix - [`MultithreadedZipContentLoader`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=marklogic%2Fmarklogic-contentpump%2Fmarklogic-contentpump-master%2Fmapreduce%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fmarklogic%2Fmapreduce%2Ftest%2FMultithreadedZipContentLoader.java#)

The interesting part is in `main()`, as defines the protocol to use the MultiMapper

```
public class MultithreadedZipContentLoader {
    public static class ZipContentMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, DocumentURI, Text> 
     {
        private DocumentURI uri = new DocumentURI();
         
        public void map(Text fileName, Text fileContent, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
              uri.setUri(fileName.toString());
              context.write(uri, fileContent);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MultithreadedZipContentLoader configFile inputDir threadCount");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(MultithreadedZipContentLoader.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(ZipContentInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, ZipContentMapper.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(DocumentURI.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(ContentOutputFormat.class);
        
        ZipContentInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        conf = job.getConfiguration();
        conf.addResource(otherArgs[0]);
         
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}

class ZipContentInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
            TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ZipContentReader();
    }
    
}

...
```

The only thing that this example lacks is the synchronize part in the extended `map` method, as in this case seems there's no need to (*no duplicate file uris, I guess*).

Comment: The `MultithreadedMapper` is interesting, thanks. But in my interesting case the data being processed is recursive and we can't just divide up the input among the threads at the beginning. I believe this means the threading implementation must therefore be custom. Thank you for clarifying the lack of thread safety in emitting values concurrently.

Comment: I've found this example: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=marklogic%2Fmarklogic-contentpump%2Fmarklogic-contentpump-master%2Fmapreduce%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fmarklogic%2Fmapreduce%2Ftest%2FMultithreadedZipContentLoader.java

Comment: Another one...but no implicit thread-safety here, just multi threaded context... https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c65efba1095a50001901821#L47

Comment: "… but doesn't implement any thread-safety mechanisms …" Yes it does. Look at the internal class `MultithreadedMapper.SubMapRecordWriter`, for example; it uses `synchronized` to access the wrapped context when writing. But that supports your point that writing to the context isn't thread safe in the default implementation.

Comment: I may be wrong again...The point is there are some thread-safe implementations, as @GarretWilson comments and correctly corrects me. The point is the MultithreadedMapper acts like the core Mapper and then you should specify the specific job mapper extension (f.e : SubMapRecordWriter, or your custom one) that will perform the map() operation

Comment: I was looking for a default Mapper in case `MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass` wasn't invoked, but seems there's no default here other than the base Mapper's `map()`. (So i was as well partially wrong on my second comment). Next fail and I shoot myself in the right hand